# Padrino + sinatra-assetpack not working

Tags: sinatra, padrino, sinatra-assetpack

I'm trying to combine Padrino with Sinatra-Assetpack, without success.

This is my Gemfile:

```rb
source :rubygems

gem 'rake'
gem 'sinatra-flash', :require => 'sinatra/flash'

# Component requirements
gem 'haml'

# Assets requirements
gem 'sinatra-assetpack', :require => 'sinatra/assetpack'

# Test requirements

# Padrino Stable Gem
gem 'padrino', '0.10.6'
```

in my app/app.rb file I set:

```rb
require 'sinatra/assetpack'

class Coffee < Padrino::Application
  register Padrino::Rendering
  register Padrino::Mailer
  register Padrino::Helpers

  register Sinatra::AssetPack

  assets {
    serve '/js',  from: '/app/assets/javascripts'
    serve '/css', from: '/app/assets/stylesheets'

    css :main, ['/css/main.css']
    js  :application, ['/js/application.js']
  }

  enable :sessions

end
```

my javascript files are in /app/assets/javascripts and css files in /app/assets/stylesheets, but Padrino respond with a 404 for both /css/main.css and /js/application.js

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Thats very weird... I started a 50pt bounty on this question, and it was never awarded by the question creator, but I did not get the 50 pts back.. whats up with that?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue, in my application anyway, but from the looks of your app.rb code it's probably the same for you;

Assetpack serves files from the directories you specify in your `serve` calls, **relative to your application's root**. In padrino, the application root is `yourapplication/app`, so if you tell assetpack to serve css from `/app/assets/stylesheets` for instance, its really looking for the files in `yourapplication/app/app/assets/stylesheets`.

The second part of the problem was that in the AssetPack docs, it shows the code

```
set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

before the `register Sinatra::AssetPack` line, which I assume is setting the application's root directory properly so that AssetPack will look in the root application directory instead of `app`. However, even If I modified that call to `set` to go up one directory from the app.rb file (since it sits in the `app` dir in Padrino), it didn't seem to have any effect on AssetPack.

In short, modifying the `from:` paths in the `serve' calls to be relative to your app directory should fix the problem. In your case, they should be:

```
serve '/js',  from: '/assets/javascripts'
serve '/css', from: '/assets/stylesheets'
```